# Rewrite iptables rules to firewall-cmd

Tags: linux, iptables

I use these iptables rules for Centos 7:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface <internet_interface> -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface <internal_interface> -j ACCEPT
```

But after reboot they are not saved even when I run `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

How I can rewrite them for `firewall-cmd`?

Comment: So your requirement is to have them working in Centos 7 using either iptables or firewall-cmd after reboot?

Comment: @TarunLalwani correct - I need them rewritten into firewall-cmd and working after reboot.

Comment: Please add the output of `systemctl status firewalld` and `systemctl status iptables`

Answer (score 0):

RHEL/CentOS offer simple methods to permanently save iptables rules for IPv4 and IPv6.
There is a service called "iptables". This must be enabled.

```
# chkconfig --list | grep iptables
  iptables          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
# chkconfig iptables on
```

The rules are saved in the file /etc/sysconfig/iptables for IPv4 and in the file /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables for IPv6. You may also use the init script in order to save the current rules.

```
# service iptables save
```

please check below link for details:

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently

Comment: Ok, but I need the rules for firewalld syntax.

Comment: firewalld is completely different interface from your question.